# Keycloak - antMatcher does not match requested path Java

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, keycloak

I am logged with correct credentials as "CHILD", so it is different than "USER" role. When I send get request with token to http://localhost:8081/iam/accounts/users, it does not allow me, and that is OK.

[image]

But when I send request to http://localhost:8081/iam/accounts/users/ (note slash is added to the end of url), I am allowed to get to this link and return body is given to me. But I should not be authorized to receive it.

[image]

My configure method. It looks working, I just dont understand why "/iam/accounts/users*" does not match also url with added slash at the end?!

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    super.configure(http);
    ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = http.cors() //
            .and() //
            .csrf().disable() //
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //
            .and() //
            .authorizeRequests();

    expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.antMatchers("/iam/accounts/users*").hasRole("USER");
    expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.antMatchers("/iam/accounts/childs*").hasRole("CHILD");

    expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/iam/accounts", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Validated
public class AccountController {

@GetMapping(path = "/users")
public String promoters() {
    return "Logged as user";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/childs")
public String supervisors() {
    return "Logged as child";
}
}
```

I am able to fix it if I add 2 lines instead of one, but why does not that antMatcher do it, if star * means that any number of characters can follow?

```
expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.antMatchers("/iam/accounts/users").hasRole("USER");
expressionInterceptUrlRegistry = expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.antMatchers("/iam/accounts/users/*").hasRole("USER");
```

Answer (score 1):

Working as expected. * matches in the same directory. / is a path separator, so it doesn't count as the same directory. user* will match user, users, but not user/.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can you please explain how should I fix it properly in 1 line code (correct regex), so path with slash is included, and this url is not exploited?